# PHP session logs out before session cookie expires

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have set up cookie lifetime to last a complete day, but after 15-20 mins of idle time, I get logged out anyways. The strangest thing is that everything runs fine on localhost, but when I took my website live, I started experiencing this problem with the same exact code.

I read on stackoverflow that it could be related to **session.gc_maxlifetime**, so I have even edited that on the .htaccess level. I have changed it from 1440 to 86400, but the problem still persists.

Here is the rundown of my code.

When a user logs in, I check if the user already has a cookie named 'AUTHID'. If the user does, I first delete it.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['AUTHID'])) {
        unset($_COOKIE['AUTHID']);
        setcookie('AUTHID', null, -1, '/');
    }
```

After that, depending on if the user selected Remember Me option, I set the cookie lifetime value, and it creates a cookie that I can see in Chrome Settings with absolutely correct expiration time.

```
session_name('AUTHID');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);

if(isset($_POST['remember-me'])) {
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 604800);
    session_set_cookie_params(604800,"/");
} else {
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
    session_set_cookie_params(86400,"/");
}

session_start();
```

Lastly, I have a php function to check if the user is logged in on every single page:

```
$rel_url = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
session_name('AUTHID');
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    if (strpos($rel_url, 'login=success') !== false) {
        header('Location: index.php');  
    }
    header('Location: login-with-bg.php?access-denied=logged-out');
    exit();
}
```

This works perfectly fine on my localhost, but when I uploaded this code on my hosting server, even though the cookie is still being created with correct expiration date, but if my browser is idle for 15-20 mins, my session gets timed out.

EDIT: from an article, I got an idea of making AJAX calls every 10 mins or so, and that works when the browser is open. However, I need a complete method that works even if the browser is closed.

EDIT2: The AJAX code that I have for keeping the session alive:

```
function keep_alive() {
    $.get('index.php',null)
}
keep_alive_interval = setInterval(keep_alive, 600000)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- Session and ajax is a tricky thing. Be sure to close your session when doing an ajax call so it writes changes to your session. (register_shutdown_function("session_write_close");)
- In this case there is no real use in changing the sessionname (default will do).
- The AUTHID cookie stores your session_id which corresponds to your session. This has to be set also. No need to manually set the cookie

This is working for me on the server but not on local machines

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1'){ // Only use custom session on server. use default settings on local machine

    register_shutdown_function("session_write_close"); // write your changes done with ajax before your session opens again

    // some security settings
    ini_set("session.use_strict_mode", 1);
    ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1);
    ini_set("session.cookie_secure", 1);
    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 1);

    ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",60 * 60 * 24 * 14); // 2 weeks
    session_set_cookie_params(60 * 60 * 24 * 14,"/",".yourdomain.com"); // 2 weeks

    session_name("AUTHID");
    if(isset($_COOKIE['AUTHID'])){
       session_id($_COOKIE['AUTHID']);
    }
}
session_start();
```

Comment: Thank you, Daan. I have taken some improvements from your code, like cookie_secure and strict mode. However, this has not helped me solve the problem. Also, I have pasted the AJAX code I am using to keep the session alive. Let me know if I have to use register_shutdown_function in this case also.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use ajax to keep the session alive. This means something else is wrong with your session setup.